# Linq's FirstOrDefault to act as other type?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0

I have this code :

```
var res1 = dtData.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(...)
            .Select(f => new { val = f["PremiumAfterUWDiscount"].ToDecimalOrZero(), 
                   idpolicy = f["IdPolicy"].ToString() })
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

however  , since this returns an anonymous type , its default value is `null` .

I want it to act as `FirstOrDefault` for `int` type.

so if there is no record , it will return 0 ( default behavior as int).

is it possible ?

*p.s. ( of course i can check it in a condition but still , i prefer the linq way).*

Comment: That won't work as it would either be returning an anonymous type or an `int` conditionally, at which point, what does `var` become? `FirstOrDefault` also provides no mechanism for defining what is "default".

Comment: What does new { val = f["PremiumAfterUWDiscount"].ToDecimalOrZero(), idpolicy = f["IdPolicy"].ToString() } do?  I don't know that syntax.

Comment: @Blam That is an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). Well worth learning about, they can be very useful.

Comment: Have you considered not using an anonymnous type? If you use a struct, it's a value type and will never be null. The members would be initialized with their defaults which would mean val = 0 and idpolicy = null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return an anonymous type that signifies "nothing" and either use the null coalescing operator:

```
var res1 = dtData.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(...)
        .Select(f => new { val = f["PremiumAfterUWDiscount"].ToDecimalOrZero(), 
               idpolicy = f["IdPolicy"].ToString() })
        .FirstOrDefault() ?? new { val = 0, idpolicy = "" };
```

Or the `DefaultIfEmpty` extension method:

```
var res1 = dtData.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(...)
        .Select(f => new { val = f["PremiumAfterUWDiscount"].ToDecimalOrZero(), 
               idpolicy = f["IdPolicy"].ToString() })
        .DefaultIfEmpty(new { val = 0, idpolicy = "" })
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

You would only be able to return an `int` in place of an anonymous type if you in fact return an `object` and cast later on (as per @recursive's answer), but this to me seems counter-productive.

`FirstOrDefault` does not offer a way to specify what "default" is.

Comment: i guess ill build an extension method something like : ZeroIfNull()

Comment: @RoyiNamir But then you'd have to cast it in order to have a return type that can change conditionally (ie, you'd be returning `object`) - in my opinion, this faff negates the syntactic sugar.

Comment: yeah i thought about returning the same structure but with 0 inside ....:) ( but it seems pretty ugly...:) )

Comment: @RoyiNamir No more ugly than the alternatives (but sometimes less). In your desired approach you would have code doing `if (res1 == 0)`, now all it needs to do is `if (res1.val == 0)`. Not much different in the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an expression evaluate to 2 different data types on two execution paths.
Also, even if that's possible, var is different to dynamic so the variable type won't be inferred by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this doesn't make any sense, and I would encourage you to think about why you want to do this, and find some cleaner, more direct way to accomplish it.

With that said, here's a small tweak to @IronicMuffin's approach that will actually work.

```
object res1 = dtData.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(...)
    .Select(f => new { 
        val = f["PremiumAfterUWDiscount"].ToDecimalOrZero(), 
        idpolicy = f["IdPolicy"].ToString() 
    })
    .FirstOrDefault() as object ?? 0;
```

I don't think this is very useful though.